How to manage compatibility of changing inherents between versions?
Basically, the title. What are the strategies around updating inherents over time and maintaining backwards-compatibility? How would I for example, take one inherent's InherentData, and update its type to be something else?
I imagine that it is not quite the same challenge of upgrading something such as runtime apis, which have versioning built in, which is why I ask.

There is no real pre-defined versioning for inherents.
I would propose that you just have different InherentIdentifiers per version of your inherent. Something like:
InherentType1
InherentType2
On the node side you can then just add both to the InherentData and the runtime can pick the one it knows.

That's a really reasonable solution, thank you! Would you accept a code change which allows decorating an inherent with a version number, and under-the-hood, it just gives a different identifier per inherent version?

Not sure we need this. The interface is already quite minimal and only expects that you pass the identifier.
